# control may reach end of non-void function in C

Tags: c, cs50

i got this bug and i can't debug it

> helpers.c:136:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function

the IDE say in last line in **}**

here is my code

```
// Calculates frequency (in Hz) of a note
int frequency(string note)
{
    // TODO
    if (strlen(note) == 2)
    {
        if (note[0] == 'A')
        {
            int freq = round(440 * (pow(2, (((int) note[1]) - 52))));
            return freq;
        }
    else
    {
        if (note[0] == 'A')
        {
            if (note[1] == '#')
            {
                int freq = round(466 * (pow(2, (((int) note[2]) - 52))));
                return freq;
            }
            else if (note[1] == 'b')
            {
                int freq = round(415 / (pow(2, (((int) note[2]) - 52))));
                return freq;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: What will it return if `note` is `"B#`?

Comment: Note that the second branch will be taken if the length is less than 2, which will lead to even more undefined behaviour.

Comment: What is a `string`? Do not hide pointers behind typedefs

Comment: looking at the 'related' list we might need a canonical q/a for this specific compiler warning.

Comment: The code has mismatched braces, which suggests that this may not be the code you are actually trying to compile.

Comment: Yes, if this code were formatted properly this error would stand out more oviously.

Comment: If the not is note A, A# or Ab there is no return statement.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker, except I suspect it would cause a different error (or additional error), so it seems more likely that it was manually transcribed rather then copy&pasted and a typo.

Comment: Actually it is further nonsense since both clauses deal with note[0] and note[1], but the first test is for a length of exactly 2.  What are the intended possible inputs?  You might do well to ask how to convert a note to frequency - you'll get a better solution than this.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but a better way of solving what you are trying to do: https://onlinegdb.com/ry7PUlQ9G

Answer (score 3):

You need a return on **all** codepaths. Let's look at your example:

```
int frequency(string note)
{
    // TODO
    if (strlen(note) == 2)
    {
        if (note[0] == 'A')
        {
            int freq = round(440 * (pow(2, (((int) note[1]) - 52))));
            return freq;
        }
        // return what?
    else
    {
        if (note[0] == 'A')
        {
            if (note[1] == '#')
            {
                int freq = round(466 * (pow(2, (((int) note[2]) - 52))));
                return freq;
            }
            else if (note[1] == 'b')
            {
                int freq = round(415 / (pow(2, (((int) note[2]) - 52))));
                return freq;
            }
            // return what?
        }
        // return what?
   }
}
```

One option is to declare a `freq` at the beginning of your code block with a default value. You would then modify this value from whichever conditions you want, and then return it at the end of the function. For example:

```
int frequency(string note)
{
    int freq = 0;
    // TODO
    if (strlen(note) == 2)
    {
        if (note[0] == 'A')
        {
            freq = round(440 * (pow(2, (((int) note[1]) - 52))));
        }
    else
    {
        if (note[0] == 'A')
        {
            if (note[1] == '#')
            {
                freq = round(466 * (pow(2, (((int) note[2]) - 52))));
            }
            else if (note[1] == 'b')
            {
                freq = round(415 / (pow(2, (((int) note[2]) - 52))));
            }
        }
   }

   return freq;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*"i got this bug and i can't debug it"*

Why can't you debug it?  I think that is one of the most straightforward and obvious of all compiler messages?

Think simply:
What will happen if `strlen(note)` is something other than `2` *(say, `3` or `7`)*?
Then what will happen next if `note[0]` is something other than `'A'` *(say, `'B'` or `'C'`)*?

Then what will your function return?

**Answer:**
Your code will reach the end of the function, which ***must*** return an `int`, but will not have returned anything!